# On page load show option from select form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I use this script below for show or hidden a few `<div>`.
The `selected` class in the script is associated with a `display:block` and my `<div>` start with a class with a `display:none`.

When the page is load all `div` are hidden. But I will like show the first of this, but I can do this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          $("select[name*='material']").change(function(){
              select_changed();
          });
      });

  function select_changed(){
      $("div[id*='mat-']").each(function(){
         $(this).removeClass('selected');
      });
      $("select[name*='material']").each(function(){
          var selected = $(this).val();
          $('#'+selected).addClass('selected');
      });
  }
```

I have already set an option like first items, but this not show up. I think the problem is all `div` in the begin have a `display:none` class.
How I can do.

For let more clear:
HTML

```
  <div class="materiali">
        <select name="material" id="material">
            <option value="mat-1">Material 1</option>
            <option value="mat-2">Material 2</option>
        </select>
     </div>

    <div class="boxx" id="mat-1">
       Materail 1
    </div>
    <div class="boxx" id="mat-2">
       Materail 2
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.boxx{
  display: none
}
.selected{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Can't get you exactly. explain with example of what you want

Comment: initially show the first div and do shorten amount of code to achieve your goal. check my answer for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already have written a function for `select_changed()` just invoke that function on ready function do as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("select[name*='material']").change(function(){
    select_changed();
  });
  select_changed() //here you can invoke your function on page ready
});

function select_changed(){
  $("div[id*='mat-']").each(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('selected');
  });
  $("select[name*='material']").each(function(){
     var selected = $(this).val();
     $('#'+selected).addClass('selected');
  });
}
```

```css
.boxx{
  display: none
}
.selected{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="materiali">
        <select name="material" id="material">
            <option value="mat-1">Material 1</option>
            <option value="mat-2">Material 2</option>
        </select>
     </div>

    <div class="boxx" id="mat-1">
       Materail 1
    </div>
    <div class="boxx" id="mat-2">
       Materail 2
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I like your option. it's easier. :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

function select_changed(){
  $("div[id*='mat-']").each(function(){
         $(this).removeClass('selected');
      });
      $("select[name*='material']").each(function(){
          var selected = $(this).val();
          $('#'+selected).addClass('selected');
      });    
};

$("select[name*='material']").change(function(){
              select_changed();
          });
          
          $("select[name*='material']").change();
});
```

```css
.boxx{
  display: none
}
.selected{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="materiali">
        <select name="material" id="material">
            <option value="mat-1">Material 1</option>
            <option value="mat-2">Material 2</option>
        </select>
     </div>

    <div class="boxx" id="mat-1">
       Materail 1</div><div class="boxx" id="mat-2">Materail 2</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reapply, but I can't not add the option "Please Select". I need to show the div with material 1. Anyway I have fix it! thank you again.

Comment: $("select[name*='material']").change();

Comment: fire change forcefully for the first time